# How to Manage Access Rights for SPEAK UI Application which is on Launchpad?

Tags: security, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-speak-ui

I have created multiple apps in SPEAK UI and placed all quick access shortcuts on the Sitecore Launchpad.

Now, how can I restrict access for some applications while creating Users, because we have Content Area in Access Viewer?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to do this. First you need to open the desktop and switch from the `Master` to the `Core` database.

If you just want to restrict access to the shortcuts on the Launchpad - you can do this by setting access rights on the shortcut items:

[image]

Create a role that should have access to the users and give that role `Read` access to the button item.

Another option would be to allow access to the application. If you look at the `Path Analyzer` you can see that some roles are denied and some granted access:

[image]

So add security rights to roles for your SPEAK apps.

Finally when you create users make sure you give them the correct roles to match what they are able to view.